# R: A simple sumatory with a loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm trying to emulate a simple sum with a for in R; i have a couple of vectors and i'm trying to achieve a simple operation and keep the added value. This is my code:

```
sum=0
for (i in 1:length(intx)-1) {
    val=((inty[i+1]-inty[i])*(intx[i+1]+intx[i]))
    print(val)
    sum=sum+val
    print(sum)
}
```

The two prints are just for debbuging; 'val' is the result of the operation in every iteration and it's printed correctly, but when i add it to 'sum', it fails, and the output is:

```
numeric(0)
```

I've tested setting the value of 'val' to a constant and then adding it to 'sum' and it works, but when 'val' is a function of i, it fails (it outputs the correct value in the print-debbuger, but fails when i add it to 'sum').

Any advice?

Comment: You probably didn't mean to do `1:length(intx)-1`. Indexing in R begins at 1. (Try adding some parens, or better yet use `seq_len`.)

Comment: That was done on purpose (it's for the formula), i'm aware it begins at 1; that range does exactly what i need. However, i added a couple of brackets to it and it worked! Thanks a lot man :D

Comment: I'm very skeptical. What numerical value do you expect inty[0] or intx[0] to have in the formula?

Comment: ? I dont expect any values at intx(0) or inty(0), i mean the loop should go from 1 to length-1 (the position before the last one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code works with joran's fix:

```
sum=0
for (i in 1:10) {
  val=i*2
  print(paste("val: ", val))
  sum=sum+val
  print(paste("sum: ", sum))
}
sum # 110 correct
```

Comment: It worked just adding brackets to the upper limit in the for -> (length(intx)-1)

Answer (score 0):

what data is there in the intx vector. If you are certain its numeric then you can force the data type to be numeric by

```
val=as.numeric((inty[i+1]-inty[i])*(intx[i+1]+intx[i]))
```

Ideally I would advice you to not use a loop at all, but lets first fix the problem you are having.

Actually I agree with the comment that your issue is about index. use 1:(length(intx)-1)